# how to get value of the texbox inside loop in asp.net using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 4 textboxes all of them take id "Ans" and number from 1 to 4

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="Ans1" runat="server" placeholder="Favorite Color"></asp:TextBox>
```

I have this loop to get value for each text box

```
        for(int i = 1 ; i<5 ; i++)
    {

        TextBox ans = FindControl (string.Concat("Ans", i.ToString()) as TextBox  != null );
    }
```

but i get this message **"can not convert type string to textbox "**

i don't know what wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a `)`

```
FindControl(string.Concat("Ans", i.ToString()))
```

I imagine it could be more readable like this

```
TextBox ans = FindControl(string.Format("Ans{0}",i)) as TextBox
```

Also, you need to remove `!= null` at the end as, whatever you're trying to do, that's not the correct place :)

Answer (score 4):

For starters, you are missing a close paren )

I think this is what you mean

```
for(int i = 1 ; i<5 ; i++)
{
    TextBox ans = FindControl(string.Concat("Ans", i.ToString())) as TextBox;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
TextBox ans = (TextBox)FindControl(string.Concat("Ans", i.ToString()));
if(ans != null)
{
    // found the textbox
}
```